# Programmatically alter the first item in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I currently render 10 colored circles that you can swipe horizontally to select. I'd like to 
programmatically alter the first item in a UICollectionView and add a little picture of a camera in the first item. The collection that is bound is just an array of RGB values. I set the first one to be all 0's so it's a unique color in that it would never be really used.

By first item, I do not want it to be the first item that scrolls in view, but rather when you can no longer scroll and you're at the literal first item in the collection.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath) {
...
...

//Define the first item as the indexpath 0,0
let firstItem:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)


if (forItemAt == myIndexPath)
 {
   coloredCircle.addSubview(cameraImageView!) 
 }
else {
   cameraImageView!.removeFromSuperview()   
 }
```

So above, my thought was that I'd check if the first item comes into view, and then add it to the subview, otherwise I'll take it away (because it seemed to be stacking up in some weird way).

Either way, trying this it exhibits some strange behavior where the first item will come into view and shows the camera, but once I stop scrolling, it just disappears.

So if I scroll slowly so the first item is out of view, and then slowly scroll it back in, it appears and works correctly!

[image]

But once I scroll left until I can't go anymore, or scroll it kinda fast, it just vanishes:

[image]

Any suggestions or ways I can make it so the first circle is permanently a little camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to put the logic inside willDisplay, instead you can simply use an UIImageView inside your coloured circle and simply hide/unhide it on the basis of indexPath. Also, put your camera image inside the ImageView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let firstItem:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    if indexPath == firstItem {
        coloredCircle.imageView.isHidden = flase
    }else{
        coloredCircle.imageView.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is elegant, simple, and most important, WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 different cell. 1 cell will contain camera view and other cell will contain colored view.

And in CellforRow method you can return appropriate cell based on your requirement.

Sorry in advance if this is not what you are looking for. As this is the first time i am answering to any question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add these Delegate, DataSource & FlowLayout Delegate

```
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Create outlet for collection view

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Define Reuse Identifier for cell

```
let reuseIdentifier = "actionCell";
```

Set Delegate & DataSource for collection view

```
currentCollectionView.delegate = self
currentCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

Register cell for collection view with reuse Iidentifier

```
currentCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ActionCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Implematation of UICollectionView Delegate, Datasource & FlowLayoutDelegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 4;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 1;
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ActionCollectionViewCell

    cell.vwAction?.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    cell.vwAction?.clipsToBounds = true

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let imgAction = UIImage(named: "Camera")
        cell.imgAction?.image = imgAction
        cell.vwAction?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    } else {

        cell.imgAction?.image = nil
        cell.vwAction?.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Function which generate random color

```
func randomColor() -> UIColor {

    let red = CGFloat(drand48())
    let green = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

ActionCollectionViewCell Desing[image]